# Directing clients to the correct page to download IE for their OS version

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows

Just build a site and we're having issues with IE7 users.  It had nothing to do with my programming, but a site we have to redirect the customers to that does not handle IE7.  Problem is that the client base is not overly tech savvy and telling them to update their version of IE requires they understand what version of Windows they're using (XP or Vista) and also whether their version is 32-bit or 64-bit which I'm sure will really scare the users off.

The issue pretty much boils down to needing to find a way to detect what version of Windows they're using (XP or Vista ... Windows 7 won't run IE7) and then find a way to alert them as to whether they're using 32-bit or 64-bit and direct them accordingly.

Not sure if anyone else has come across this problem and curious how they've handled it.

Comment: I was under the impression that Microsoft did that for you at this link... `http://www.microsoft.com/windows/Internet-explorer/default.aspx`  - Could be wrong, but that's where we direct users with IE7 and below on some of our sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to find the useragent using javascript, use this

```
var user_agent = navigator.userAgent
```

The output to the above command on my machine is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7
```

Answer (score 0):

The UserAgent string in the http header can often be used to determine their OS, Browser, and their architecture (32 vs 64).